# Visual Basic 2008 - color

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code, but I don't have any idea what happens in this code. So I don't know how to prepare an interface for this. Someone please tell me what the purpose of the array "Mylist" is. I haven't worked with "color" keyword before. Thanks in advance

```
    Dim Mylist(4) As Color
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 4
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Mylist(i) = Color.White
        Else
            Mylist(i) = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The "purpose" of Mylist is whatever the person who wrote the code intended it to be. It is an array of five Colors. The code sets Mylist(0), Mylist(2) and Mylist(4) to White, and Mylist(1), Mylist(3) to Red.

Comment: What is meant by setting Mylist(0) to White

Comment: @AlexGrahm: Color is a structure that represents a colour (for example, the colour of an item in your form). Mylist is an array that contains five Color objects, and Mylist(0) is the first element in that array. Color.White is a Color structure that represents the colour "White". So `Mylist(0) = Color.White` sets the first element of the Mylist array to a value that represents the colour "White".